# Private extension updates

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I have created an extension for visual studio code. This extension is private and to be used internally by ourselves and our customers.

I have produced a vsix file which i could distribute manually however, this extension is updated regularly. For this reason it would be great if we could provide updates in a similar way to published extensions. Is this possible?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev i don't understand your response?

Comment: It was a response to first version of your post.

Comment: duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41669255/vscode-private-extension-repository-for-teams