# VSCode Private Extension Repository for teams

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I'm writing highly specific **private VSCode extensions** for our dev team. I will be making constant changes to these extensions. From what I've read, the only way is to compile the extension as a .vsix file and send this file to each of the team.

This workflow is tedious and feels unnecessary.

I am looking for a more *automatic* and *transparent* solution, which more or less updates the private extension automatically.

Has this scenario been solved?

Comment: It's not very likely that Microsoft is going to cover this requirement (as several years have passed), and open source solutions out there are limited in features and freshness. My company is selling a commercial solution on this, https://www.scarborough.market

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Not as of VSCode 1.14 but we are tracking the feature request here: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/21839

Comment: @DanielLizik: what brings you to this conclusion? Since it explicitely still says there (when I open your link) "If you want to share your extension with others privately, you ***can send*** them your packaged extension .vsix file" - Is your link maybe wrong?

Comment: End of July 2021 they added this to their road map  - see https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/pull/129764#issuecomment-889155248 and as mentioned above https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/21839#issuecomment-889183056 
Looks promising now

Answer (score 1):

**2023 / v1.79.2** : You may consider this extension pack

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=garmin.private-extension-manager

> Private Extension Manager lets you find, install, and update extensions from any NPM registry. This lets you distribute organization-specific extensions using a private registry server such as Sonatype Nexus or Verdaccio.

Answer (score 0):

I write an [extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=yangzhao.auto-updater&ssr=false#overview) to allow you to auto update your extension from any url (like a private hosting site)